# ¿Cómo imprimir texto de manera correcta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Sucede que puedo ejecutar correctamente el programa, no me dice que tengo ningún error. Sin embargo, en la pantalla de salida, a pesar de que imprime lo que deseo, además, el comando "prin" imprime todo aquello que esté debajo, tal como lo muestro en las imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mostrando en pantalla parte del código que he digitado. No comprendo que estoy haciendo mal o si mi compilador está fallando.

Soy primerizo en Python.
Codigo original:

```
A = input("Ingrese un valor")
print(A)
```

Salida:

```
Ingrese un valorprint(A)
>>> A = input("Ingrese un valor")
Ingrese un valorprint(A)
>>> 5
5
>>>
```

Comment: que editor estas utilizando, es un error poco común, justo acabo de replicar tu código utilizando python 3.7.2 y todo va correcto.

Comment: Python 3.7.3 tengo yo y estoy ocupado Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Por favor, comparte tu código y la salida de la ejecución como texto. A menos que sea trabajo con una GUI, siempre será más fácil replicar todo así.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La única forma en que he conseguido replicar el comportamiento que muestras en tus capturas de pantalla desde Visual Studio Code ha sido la siguiente:

1. Abro Visual Studio Code
2. Edito un archivo y en él escribo el código:

   ```
   A = input("Numero?")
   print(A)
   ```
3. Abro una terminal con el comando "Nueva terminal", lo que causa que el editor divida en dos su ventana y aoarezca un símbolo de sistema en la parte inferior.
4. Tecleo en esa parte inferior `python` y pulso retorno de carro, lo que hace aparecer el prompt `>>>`
5. Selecciono con el ratón el código que había escrito en el paso 2 y lo copio al portapapeles con Ctrl+C
6. Con Ctrl+V pego el código seleccionado en el prompt `>>>`

Entonces puedo ver exactamente lo que indicas en tu segunda captura de pantalla. Lo cual es lógico, pues el intérprete `>>>` ejecuta las líneas de una en una. La primera que recibe es `A=input(...)`, por lo que se queda esperando a lo que teclees después, para guardarlo en `A`, y lo siguiente que aparece (que llega del portapapeles) es el texto `print(A)`, que es lo que guarda en la variable `A`.

Tras ello imprime de nuevo el prompt `>>>` invitándote a teclear otro comando Python. En ese momento tú pones `5`, creyendo que estás respondiendo al `input()`. Pero no, el `input()` ya había terminado. Ahora le estás enviando el 5 directamente al intérprete, el cual lo evalúa, encuentra que el resultado es `5` y eso es lo que te muestra. No te está mostrando  `A`. Tras ello de nuevo sale el prompt `>>>` invitándote a teclear otro comando.

Si en ese momento pusieras `A`, y pulsaras retorno de carro, verías el valor que se ha guardado en la variable `A`, que no es otro que lo que `input()` recibió, y que es la cadena `print(A)`. Mira:

```
>>> A
'print(A)'
```

### Cómo hacerlo bien

Todo lo anterior ocurre porque esa no es la forma de ejecutar un programa python desde Visual Studio Code. Lo que tienes que hacer es pulsar `F5` desde el editor (no sin antes haber guardado el contenido del editor en un fichero `.py`). Entonces se ejecutará tu código y se verá en la terminal el resultado.

<s>Otra opción es que instales la extensión *Code Runner*, que te permite hacer clic con el botón derecho sobre la ventana del editor para elegir la opción "Run Code".</s> **Editado** Esta extensión muestra la salida en un panel que no admite entrada. No se puede usar con `input()`.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que estás confundiendo el propósito de `input()`. Lo que hace es recibir una entrada que ingresas a través del teclado. Por lo tanto, cuando haces esto:

```
>>> A = input("Ingrese un valor: ")
Ingrese un valor: Hola
>>>
```

Lo que ha pasado es que se ha guardado la cadena `"Hola"` en la variable `A`. Lo que tú estás tratando de hacer es hacer un `print(A)` para ver el valor que contiene pero eso tienes que hacerlo luego. Es decir:

```
>>> A = input("Ingrese un valor: ") # Solicitar por teclado
Ingrese un valor: Hola
>>> print(A) # Imprimir el valor
Hola
>>> type(A) # ¿De qué tipo es A?
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Comprendo lo que tratas de decirme (a expeción del type, que dezconozco para que lo estás utlizando) pero no entiendo porqué lo estoy haciendo mal en mi caso. Ya subiré código y salida en formato de texto,

Comment: @GabrielHernández lo del type es para que veas que lo que retorna finalmente `input()` es una cadena de texto. Lo digo ara que tengas cuidado al tratar de usar números.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que estas escribiendo tu script desde el shell de python pasa lo siguiente:

```
>>>A = input("ingrese un valor")
ingrese un valorprint(A)
```

En este punto tu variable A esta guardando el valor 'print(A)', ese 5 que aparece es por que una nueva linea de codigo, siempre que tengas estos caracteres >>> representa codigo, cuando no aparecen representan tu entrada por teclado

Tu Script debe ir algo como esto:

```
>>>A=input("ingrese un valor ")
ingrese un valor 5
>>>print(A)
5
```

Comment: No estoy en el Shell de Python, estoy usando Visual Studion Code.

Comment: Me refiero a que estas corriendo tu código desde la consola, es decir escribes C://python y es cuando te aparece el shell de python con esto >>>, no importa si es la consola integrada de VSCode o de CMD

Comment: ¿Entonces yo debo digitar en el editor de código los '>>>' para indicar que es código y no texto?